# how to count days between column q.atindt and q.orderdate? cause i am not getting right figures in some cases

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am trying to get the difference between two dates `q.atindt-q.orderdate`, but in some cases I am getting figures like multiplied twice or three, sometimes it looks it does not have pattern in calculation , I have tried max function, but it did not work ....

````
concat(q.CHSeries, q.CHNumber) as "Chassi no.",
q.CHNumber as "Chassi no.2",
q.CHNumber *1 as "Chassi no.1",
q.Model,
q.ORDER,
q.atindt as "Date of Invoice",
q.atinvn as "Invoice no",
q.customer as "Customer",
q.orderdate as "Orderdate",
(select coalesce(sum(lyamnt*lyICVL),0) from thf311 where q.order=lyorno)+
(select coalesce(sum(nmamnt*nmICVL),0) from thf351 where  q.order=nmorno) as "Workshop Sales",
(select coalesce(sum(lxamnt*lxICVL),0) from thf310 where  q.order=lxorno) +
(select coalesce(sum(nlamnt*nlICVL),0) from thf350 where  q.order=nlorno)as "Part Sales",
(select coalesce(sum(lyamnt*lyICVL),0) from thf311 where  q.order=lyorno) + (select coalesce(sum(lxamnt*lxICVL),0) from thf310 where q.order=lxorno)+
(select coalesce(sum(nmamnt*nmICVL),0) from thf351 where  q.order=nmorno) + (select coalesce(sum(nlamnt*nlICVL),0) from thf350 where  q.order=nlorno)
 as "Total Sales",
q.atindt-q.orderdate 
FROM 
(select ATVIN2, ATVIN3, ATPRDT, ATGNN2, aTorno, nlpcno, atindt, atinvn, atca30, atordt FROM THF020 h, THF350 WHERE nlBRNN=h.AtGNN2 AND nlORNO=h.AtORNO union select AtVIN2, AtVIN3, AtPRDT, AtGNN2, atorno, nmpcno, atindt, atinvn, atca30, atordt 
FROM THF020 h, THF351 WHERE nmBRNN=h.AtGNN2 AND nmORNO=h.AtORNO
union
select AJVIN2, AJVIN3, AJPRDT, AJGNN2, ajorno, lxpcno, ajindt, ajinvn, ajca30,ajordt FROM THF010 h, THF310 WHERE lxBRNN=h.AjGNN2 AND lxORNO=h.AjORNO union select AjVIN2, AjVIN3, AjPRDT, AjGNN2, ajorno, lypcno, ajindt, ajinvn, ajca30, ajordt
FROM THF010 h, THF311 WHERE lyBRNN=h.AjGNN2 AND lyORNO=h.AjORNO) as q(CHSeries, CHNumber, Model, BRANCH, ORDER, PAYCDE, atindt, atinvn, customer,orderdate)
where atindt>='2019-01-01' and atindt<='2019-10-25' and paycde>39 and paycde <60  and concat(q.CHSeries, q.CHNumber) in 
(chassi 1,
chassi2) 
group by
concat(q.CHSeries, q.CHNumber),
q.CHNumber,
q.CHNumber,
q.Model,
q.branch,
q.ORDER,
q.atindt,
q.atinvn,
q.customer,
q.orderdate```
````

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Lajos DB vizualizer

Comment: That's not a dbms, that's a query tool. Which dbms do you connect to?

Comment: To get assistance I recommend simplifying the problem, and adding some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh  DB2 from IBM iseries

Comment: Is DAYS(q.atindt)-DAYS(q.orderdate) solving your problem?

Comment: @LajosArpad your solution worked, thank you , but can you explain me why it did not work with my code ? thanx a lot

Comment: Of course. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `DAYS`:

```
DAYS(q.atindt)-DAYS(q.orderdate)
```

The reason is that the arithmetics of date differences will not always evaluate to days, see:

> If DAY(DATE2) <= DAY(DATE1) then DAY(RESULT) = DAY(DATE1) - DAY(DATE2)
>
> If DAY(DATE2) > DAY(DATE1) then DAY(RESULT) = N + DAY(DATE1) -
>   DAY(DATE2) where N = the last day of MONTH(DATE2). MONTH(DATE2) is
>   then incremented by 1.
>
> If MONTH(DATE2) <= MONTH(DATE1) then MONTH(RESULT) = MONTH(DATE1) -
>   MONTH(DATE2)
>
> If MONTH(DATE2) > MONTH(DATE1) then MONTH(RESULT) = 12 + MONTH(DATE1)
>   - MONTH(DATE2) and YEAR(DATE2) is incremented by 1.
>
> YEAR(RESULT) = YEAR(DATE1) - YEAR(DATE2)

At: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_datearithmetic.html